# Exception while running weblogicImportMetaData.sh

Tags: weblogic, metadata, wlst, oim

I am running weblogicImportMetaData.sh with `weblogic` user its working fine but for the `xelsysadm` its failing with the following exception:

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_OIM/server/bin/weblogicImportMetadata.py", line 21, in ?
  File "/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/oracle_common/common/wlst/mdsWLSTCommands.py", line 298, in importMetadata
  File "/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/oracle_common/common/wlst/mdsWLSTCommands.py", line 850, in executeAppRuntimeMBeanOperation
  File "/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/oracle_common/common/wlst/mdsWLSTCommands.py", line 1131, in saveStackAndRaiseException
WLSTException: java.lang.SecurityException: MBean operation access denied.
  MBean: oracle.mds.lcm:name=MDSAppRuntime,type=MDSAppRuntime,Application=OIMAppMetadata,ApplicationVersion=11.1.2.0.0
  Operation: importMetadata(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.String;, [Ljava.lang.String;, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, java.lang.String)
  Detail: Access denied. Required roles: Admin, executing subject: principals=[BIReportAdministrator, SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS, xelsysadm, challengenotset]
 MDS-91009: Operation "importMetadata" failure. Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to put xelsysadm in the weblogic realm so as to enable xelsysadm to run `webloginMetadataImport.sh`